# Convert Rows to Columns SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server

I have a query which return set of records it's recipe information. My query is

```
    SELECT distinct RIG.RecipeNumber,  RIG.Serving_Size_Yield_Quantity as 'Recipe Yield', RCS.Description as 'Serving Size', rcs.Quantity as 'Quantity to Serve',
mri.MenuCountType_Description
FROM RecipeIngredientInfo RIG JOIN RECIPE_SERVINGSIZE RCS ON
RIG.RECIPE_RECID = RCS.RecipeID  
JOIN MenuRecipeInfo MRI ON MRI.RecipeID =  RIG.RECIPE_RECID
WHERE MenuCountType_Description is NOT NULL AND RIG.RecipeNumber ='___  900324'
Order By RecipeNumber
```

Query returns in the below format :

[image]

I want the data to be in below format :  Group By RecipeNumber, Servig Size and then MenuCountType_Description should be columns.

Query to get MenuCountType_Descritions is:

```
select DISTINCT MenuCountType_Description
from MenuRecipeInfo WHERE MenuCountType_Description IS NOT NULL
```

[image]

Comment: There are two things going on here. first you want to PIVOT your data but you also are wanting to get the values as column headers. Both have been answered around here dozens and dozens of times. Start by pivoting your data, then get the column headers the way you want.

Comment: I have not worked mush on SQL, so would need any help.. Please help me..

Comment: Anything I do at this point is doing it for you which is not going to help you. What have you tried? Did you even search this site for "sql server pivot"?

Comment: I have went through PIVOT but I see examples using Aggregate fucntions for examples like sum of invoice something like that... I could not apply that

Comment: Any help please.....I am in immediate need please..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess I am close with this query

```
SELECT 
    *
    from
    (
    SELECT distinct RIG.RecipeNumber,  RIG.Serving_Size_Yield_Quantity as 'Recipe Yield', RCS.Description as 'ServingSize', rcs.Quantity as 'Quantity to Serve', 'X' flag,
    mri.MenuCountType_Description
    FROM RecipeIngredientInfo RIG JOIN RECIPE_SERVINGSIZE RCS ON
    RIG.RECIPE_RECID = RCS.RecipeID  
    JOIN MenuRecipeInfo MRI ON MRI.RecipeID =  RIG.RECIPE_RECID
    WHERE MenuCountType_Description is NOT NULL AND RIG.RecipeNumber ='___  900324'
    ) SRC
    pivot
    (
    max(flag)
    for MenuCountType_Description in ([LYFE], [Grades 6-8], Supper,Snack, Employees, [Adults/Visitors], [Grades K-8], [Grades 9-12])
    ) piv;
```

Comment: Looks like you are close. Glad you are getting it.